# Using quotes and double quotes in Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)

Tags: java, unix, lisp, runtime, runtime.exec

I am trying to start a Lisp Image from Java in Mac OSX. Using the Image from my console I type the following:

```
lisp_image --eval '(package::method "some_argument")'
```

everything runs fine.

In Java I have the problem to pass the quotes and double quotes using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lisp_image --eval '(package::method \"some_argument\")'").`

I also tried to use :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"lisp_image", "--eval ", "\'(package::method ", 
           "--eval ", "\"", "some_argument", "\")", "\'"});
```

and various things with escaping using the backslash. Nothing works.... Using String Array seems to work only for Unix (or Windows) commands.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Sven

Comment: Did you look at: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand it you want to invoke the list_image with two arguments, --eval and '(package::method \"some_argument\")' where the single quotes is just there to prevent the shell from breaking it up into multiple arguments.

Then you should use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"lisp_image", "--eval", "(package::method \"some_argument\")"});
```

Comment: GREAT !  It's the single quotes :-) Thank you so much !

Comment: @svendeswan, you may want to accept the answer if its worked for you :-)