# Java Runtime.exec() arguments on Linux

Tags: java, linux-kernel, runtime, runtime.exec

Okay so here is the problem:
I have 3 classes MyClass1 and MyClass2 and ExecClass.
I go to my command prompt and do this:

```
$java MyClass1 -exec "java MyClass2 arg1 arg2"
```

which works perfectly.
Now in ExecClass I have the following line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java MyClass1 -exec \"java MyClass2 arg1 arg2\"");
```

Problem is if you print the second string its exactly the same as the first, but when my ExecClass runs it MyClass1 complains: Unrecognized argument arg1 and fails.
After a bit of debugging I found out that in the first case when I'm calling directly from the terminal the whole string in the quotes is 1 argument (arg[1]), where in the second case the arg.length = 5 and it basically splits them... for some unkown reason to me. 
I just need to know a workarround that if someone knows, aka my Runtime.exec() to works.
PS: On my Windows machine such problem does not occur only on the linux. It's a ubuntu destrution Kernel: 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java with the exact question and two potential answers.

Comment: For pities sake, start using `ProcessBuilder`!

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, worked great. Am.. I havent used ProcessBuilder ever, cause I kinda stopped using java a while ago but might look at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using quotes and double quotes in Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413254/using-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-java-runtime-getruntime-exec)

Comment: You can also use ProcessBuilder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7134525/2006412

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runtime.exec`, unlike `system()`-like functions in other languages, does not invoke a shell to parse the command (and double quoted strings are a shell feature).

To split the string the way you want it, use the Runtime.exec that accepts a String array:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "java", "MyClass1", "-exec", "java MyClass2 arg1 arg2"});
```